# Alterando valores tabela usando UPDATE CASE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

olá, eu tenho uma tabela deste modelo:

```
+-------------------------------+
|        participacao           |
+----+--------+------+----------+
| id | nome   | equipe | ativo  | 
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 1  | luiz   |  A     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 2  | carlos |  A     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 3  | maria  |  C     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 4  | maria  |  D     |   1    | 
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 5  | carlos |  E     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

eu gostaria de fazer um update nos valores da coluna 'ativo' no qual quando eu alterasse o 'nome' para uma 'equipe' e este nome aparecesse duplicado nesta equipe ocorresse o update para **'0'** se não deixa **'1'**,
**exemplo:** NOME='luiz' no lugar de nome='carlos' na equipe=A e na equipe=E

```
+-------------------------------+
|          participacao         |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | nome   | equipe | ativo  | 
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 1  | luiz   |  A     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 2  | luiz   |  A     |   0    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 3  | maria  |  C     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 4  | bia    |  A     |   0    | 
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| 5  | luiz   |  E     |   1    |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

eu vi uns exemplos e estou aplicando desta forma:

```
UPDATE participacao SET nome = CASE  
WHEN nome = carlos AND equipe = A THEN nome = luiz, ativo = 0  
WHEN nome = carlos AND equipe !=A THEN nome = luiz, ativo = 1  
END  
WHERE nome in (carlos);
```

porem não está funcionando
aceito sugestoes,obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você deve que colocar os valores entre aspas (exceto os numéricos). Por exemplo, em vez de `nome = carlos`, use `nome = 'carlos'`.

E para alterar as duas colunas (`nome` e `ativo`) você faz dois `CASE`, sendo o primeiro alterando a coluna `ativo` e em seguida a coluna `nome`:

```
UPDATE participacao SET
ativo = CASE
WHEN nome = 'carlos' AND equipe = 'A' THEN 0
WHEN nome = 'carlos' AND equipe != 'A' THEN 1
END,
nome = CASE
WHEN nome = 'carlos' AND equipe = 'A' THEN 'luiz'
WHEN nome = 'carlos' AND equipe != 'A' THEN 'luiz'
END
WHERE nome IN ('carlos');
```

Comment: Sam muito obrigado, marquei sua resposta como a que me tirou muitas duvidas e me ajudou na resolução do problema, valeu pelo seu tempo em ajudar!!

Answer (score 1):

seria dois comandos:

```
UPDATE participacao SET ativo = 0 WHERE nome = 'luiz' AND equipe = 'A';
UPDATE participacao SET nome = 'carlos' WHERE id = 2
```

Comment: opa amigo obrigado pelo seu tempo, eu precisava não buscar pelo id pois o mesmo na minha tabela e 'AUTO INCREMENT', sua resposta me ajudou a esclarecer muitas coisas!!